Evaluation of LR Model in PYSPARK
How do you write an Evaluation metrics code to evaluate L.R. model performance in pyspark?
Data frame:
data = spark.createDataFrame([
(0, 18.0, "male", 5.0, 35000),
(1, 20.0, "female", 3.0, 45000),
(2, 22.0, "male", 8.0, 58000),
(3, 25.0, "female", 2.0, 62000),

], ["id", "age", "gender", "experience", "salary"])
accuracy = evaluator_accuracy.evaluate(predictions)
precision = evaluator_precision.evaluate(predictions)
recall = evaluator_recall.evaluate(predictions)
f1 = evaluator_f1.evaluate(predictions)

It has an error

did you done  string indexing for categorical cols and vectrization for good model fit

what kind of error you are getting

Try like this it is working code notebooklink
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

Session creation here
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("lr").getOrCreate()

data frame
data = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 18.0, "male", 5.0, 35000),
    (1, 20.0, "female", 3.0, 45000),
    (2, 22.0, "male", 8.0, 58000),
    (3, 25.0, "female", 2.0, 62000),
    (4, 28.0, "female", 4.0, 70000)
], ["id", "age", "gender", "experience", "salary"])


indexing the catagorical cols for model
# Index the categorical column "gender"
ind = StringIndexer(inputCol="gender", outputCol="genderIndex")
data = ind.fit(data).transform(data)

Creating feautre col and model training
assem = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["age", "experience", "salary", "genderIndex"],
    outputCol="features"
)
data = assem.transform(data)


data = data.withColumn("label", (data.salary > 50000).cast("double"))


train, test = data.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=1234)


model= LogisticRegression(featuresCol="features", labelCol="label")

lr_model = model.fit(train)

getting evalualtions
pred = lr_model.transform(test)

evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy"
)
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(pred)

precision_eval = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="weightedPrecision"
)
precision = precision_eval.evaluate(pred)

recall_eval = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="weightedRecall"
)
recall = recall_eval.evaluate(pred)

f1_eval = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="f1"
)
f1 = f1_eval.evaluate(pred)
print(f1)
spark.stop()



Please explain how this code actually addresses the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

Please share some comments on the code @n_dev

use the link there are all code placed and working

and code is well commented just check it out

@SabrinaCheruiyot I've make sections in the answers please  consider them comments

okay thanks@ n_dev

if you have any problem in understanding just comment I'll explain you

also this code is working fine just give it a try
